# Modify a string in a file with perl

Tags: perl

I have a file, d00.dat, and I need to change the string d01 for d02...With the following code it prints in the console the modificatons but they are not changed in the file d00.dat...how can I do that?

```
my $line = 0;
my $filename = "d00.dat";
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) || die "file could not open $! \n";
while( $line = <$fh>) {
if( $line =~ s/d01/d02/g ){
print "$line\n";
}
```

Comment: You are just reading file and printing the replaced string, How it will reflect in the file? You should use `sed` with `system` command in `perl` to achieve this.

Comment: @AbhiNickz There's no need to resort to sed, perl can do "in-place" modifications just fine.

Comment: Yes but Enric just written code to read a file so I suggested another way to modify file,

Comment: Tie::File is never* the answer! (* ok, almost)

Comment: Not tested: `perl -pi.bak -e 's/d01/d02/g' d00.dat`

Comment: ... as opposed to Tie::Fighter which is always* the answer! (* ok, almost) ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are thinking about changing just those places, you can't -- have to replace the whole file.<sup>†</sup>

You can print out each line, including the changes, to another file, then copy that over.  Many tools work that way.  Or, you can read in all lines, change them as suitable, and then overwrite the file.

```
my $filename = "d00.dat";

open(my $fh, '<', $filename) || die "file could not open $! \n";
my @new_lines = map { s/d01/d02/g; $_ } <$fh>;
close $fh;

open(my $fh_out, '>', $filename) || die "file could not open $! \n";
print $fh_out $_  for @new_lines;
close $fh_out;
```

---

Since `open` will close a filehandle if opened already you can also do

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
my @new_lines = map { s/d01/d02/gr } <$fh>;

open $fh, '>', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
print $fh $_  for @new_lines;
close $fh;
```

where I dropped parens and changed to `or`, and added the `$filename` to the error message. I also use the `/r` modifier in regex ("*non-destructive substitution*"), with which the changed string is returned -- exactly as needed for that `map`, so now we don't need that lone `$_` at the end of the block.

A newline at the end of `die` message, present in the question, has one subtle consequence: it suppresses information about the line number at which the `die` was emitted.  While this is sometimes desired, in most cases it isn't and here we certainly want to see the line number of *that* call which failed!  So I removed that additional newline in `die`'s message.

---

<sup>†</sup> A file is a sequence of bytes.  So if we want to replace a `nope` with `yes` ... what happens with the last character, `e`, once we replaced the first three? We have to move the rest of the file, following the original `nope`, to overwrite the `e` and so to now follow `yes`. So we need to overwrite the rest of the file, and in practice it's far easier to just replace the whole file.

If we wanted to replace the `nope` with `yeah` ... well, now it's four-for-four and we could in fact just overwrite those four characters. However, that's rarely the case and is more complicated to do.

While the question asks to replace`d01` with `d02` I'd imagine that this is an example while in practice the strings aren't of the same length in general. Even if they are ... replacing the file is much easier and safer, and most likely no efficiency loss will be noticed.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, fastest solution is read the file into memory, make the change, then write the changes back to the file.

```
my $qfn = "d00.dat";

my $file;
{
   open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
      or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

   local $/;
   $file = <$fh>;
}

$file =~ s/d01/d02/g;

{
   open(my $fh, '>', $qfn)
      or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");

   print($fh $file);
}
```

As a one-liner:

```
perl -i -pe's/d01/d02/g' d00.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl has a switch to modify files in-place. I think that is what you are looking for:

```
perl -i.bak -p -e 's/d01/d02/g;' d00.dat
```

This will

- rename `d00.dat` to `d00.dat.bak`
- read `d00.dat.bak`
- replace every occurence of `d01` with `d02`
- print the resulting line to `d00.dat`

Explanation:

- `-i` edits files in-place and optionally makes a backup if some suffix is given.
  E.g. `-i.bak` will create `$file.bak`, `-i.before` will create `$file.before` etc.
  Without a suffix (only `-i`) there will be *no backup* so consider this dangerous.
- `-p` places a loop like

  ```
  while(<>) {
      # your code
      print;
  }
  ```

  around your code (`s/…/…/g;`) in this case
- `-e` simply means *"execute the following statement"*.